# How to know the branch name in an arcanist event

Tags: git, events, phabricator

Below my class:

```
class JenkinsDiffEventListener extends PhutilEventListener {

  public function register() {
    $this->listen(ArcanistEventType::TYPE_DIFF_WASCREATED);
  }

  public function handleEvent(PhutilEvent $event) {
    $diff_id = $event->getValue('diffID');

    /* Need to send a get request to jenkins to trigger the job. We pass the
     * diff id to jenkins via its api.
     */
    $workflow = $event->getValue('workflow');
    $jenkins_uri = $workflow->getConfigFromAnySource('jenkins.uri');
    $jenkins_jobs = $workflow->getConfigFromAnySource('jenkins.jobs');

    if (!$jenkins_uri || !$jenkins_jobs) {
      return;
    }

    foreach ($jenkins_jobs as $job) {
        $url = $jenkins_uri."/job/".$job."/buildWithParameters?DIFF_ID=".$diff_id;
        file_get_contents($url);
    }
  }
}
```

Do you know how can I get the name of the current git branch from this class?
I would like to do something as below:

```
$branch = $workflow->getSomething()->getBranch();
$url = $jenkins_uri."/job/".$job."/buildWithParameters?DIFF_ID=".$diff_id."&BRANCH=".$branch;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer :

```
$branch = $workflow->getRepositoryAPI()->getBranchName();
```

Thanks